# Ubuntu 17.04 - No internet connection in live session

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I just want to preface that I am a complete beginner with Linux. I am trying out 17.04 from a USB stick and can't connect to the internet at all. My ethernet connection is showing up on the connection list but Firefox, the 'browser' program nor anything that would pull information from the internet like Amazon can't connect. Willing to post any information needed.

Edit: I've been trying to solve the issue myself for a few hours now. Have tried to add Google's DNS settings, tried restarting the Network Manager and the steps [here on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358631).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use Ubuntu 17.04. Prob an earlier version of Ubuntu does not have the bug and works fine.

---

This has not really to do with you question, but handy to know when you have problem with networkmanager.

Remove modemmanager to avoid eventually conflict with the wireless driver. You don´t need it.

In terminal *(the password will not be visible)*

```
sudo apt remove modemmanager
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, I just downgraded to 16.04 and it's working fine. Think I'll stick with this until 17.10. Hopefully it'll be fixed then.